# Email sent via script is not delivered

Tags: php, html, forms

I am a php beginner and I am trying to send form data via email using the php mail() function. For some reason my form is being processed and goes to the thank you page but I am not receiving the emails with the data.
I checked my code but can't find what is wrong! can someone please give me a hand?
Here is the sample of my code:

```
<form class="form-wrapper" action="process_form.php" method="post">

      <label for="costumer_name">First Name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="costumer_first_name"/>

<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This is the process_form.php code

```
<?php
$CustomerFirstName = $_POST['customer_first_name'];

// Build the email 

$to = "my@mailinator.com";
$headers = "From: $Email";
$subject = "Red T-shirt Web Order";
$message = "Red T-shirt Order Information:\n\n
Customer First Name:".$CustomerFirstName."\n";

// Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


// Redirect
header("Location: thank_you.php");
?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: is it a windows server or linux server?

Comment: also on this line `$headers = "From: $Email";` where is `$Email` created

Comment: Is your mailer configured?  What SMTP service are you using to send the mail?  Is there an error coming back from it?

Comment: is there any error in log file?

Comment: You should try removing the header location to see what error output is given. Other than that, it's possibly how the server is configured and the PHP restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Try just making a static call with:

```
mail('your@email.com', 'Test Subject', 'Test Message');
```

If that doesn't work, then it is probably your SMTP server, or lack thereof.

Edit: Also, since $Email is not sent, you're sending a header of 'From: ', which is an invalid header, and will probably cause SMTP to crap out. I know it does on our server, which uses MailEnable, because I've encountered the exact bug before.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be on this line:

```
$headers = "From: $Email";
```

i dont see `$Email` ever instantiated in your code.

Also `mail()` works differently for Windows and Linux.

Comment: I think it is the solution to the problem. Accept this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed specify the SMTP host name

Comment: you dont need to do that if it is Linux. the OP did not specify

Answer (score 0):

`$CustomerFirstName = $_POST['customer_first_name'];`

`<input type="text" name="costumer_first_name"/>`

customer_first_name
costumer_first_name

Spot the difference! `:-)`

Also, `$Email` not defined and inside quotes, Would need to be defined and `"From: " . $Email;`

Answer (score 0):

As Neal mentioned you didn't collect the Email from the form or grab the value for that variable in your PHP code.

Also $CustomerFirstName will not be inserted into your $message with anything because in your PHP code you refer it as

```
$CustomerFirstName = $_POST['customer_first_name'];
```

whereas customer is spelled with the letter u but in your HTML you spelled it with a letter o.

Comment: yes, that is true, but that is mail content, not the `mail()` function.